# Detecting a pattern in RX, and converting the stream

Tags: system.reactive

I have a stream of decimal numbers and I need to detect a certain pattern and then emit a signal with no value.  So I think I need to write SelectMany but I'm not sure how to go about this.  In order to detect the pattern, I'll need to keep the state of the last few numbers.  How should I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use buffer with a sliding window. For example a sliding window of 5

```
source.Buffer(5,1).Where(p=>MatchPattern(p)).Select(p=>Unit.Default)
```

where

```
bool MatchPattern(List<T> t){
    // Some code to return true or false if pattern is met
}
```

`Unit` is a type used to mean `no value`

Comment: This will detect the pattern, but how do you keep streamed values from before and after the match from being streamed? In your case you are only returning Unit and not returning any stream values (minus the matching values)

Comment: The last value in the list is the current value in the observable sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Try using Window with a count of the number of items you want to check and then a where clause to compare against your input. The issue I would see here is that if you have a window of 3 over the following sequence - 12345 and you are checking for 234, the filter would catch 234, but would pass through 123 and 345, thus you would still get the full listing and the matching values wouldn't be filtered out. Thus the window option would work for detecting the pattern, but not necessarily extracting the pattern from the stream.